# Scroll right side div in a parent container

Tags: html, css

I am making a scrollable section like in this theme https://nex.vamtam.com/ (the green section "**Sustainability Goals**")

Please see below is my code was trying to achieve the right side divs don't scroll in the main green container.

```css
.scroll{background-color: #28c624; height: 100vh; position: relative;}

.div-left{
    background-color: red;
    width:40%;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    position: sticky;
 will-change: transform, position;
 height: 120px;
 top: 0;
 margin-top: 50px;
 left: 40px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.div-right-1{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
} 

.div-right-2{
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    margin:0px;
    float: right;
}
.div-right-3{
    background-color: pink;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    margin:0px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">   
    <div class= "div-left div-left-small">
      
DELIVERING INNOVATION
Sustainability
goals

We are an integrated engineering company comprised of agile and experienced engineers skilled in different types of engineering work.
    </div>
    <div class= "div-right-1 div-right-1-small">Environment</div>
    
    <div class="clear"></div>
    
    <div class= "div-right-2 div-right-2-small">Health & Safety</div>
    
    <div class="clear"></div>
    
    <div class="div-right-3 div-right-3-small">Integrity</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're probably looking for a parallax scrolling effect. Try something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_parallax. Or even better, use [materialize](https://materializecss.com/parallax.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the height of the wrapping container the same height as all three items on the right added together. I have used vh as it looks like you are making them fill the screen height and vh is easy to calculate in CSS. See below example.

```css
.scroll {
  background-color: #28c624;
  height: 300vh;
  position: relative;
}

.div-left {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
  position: sticky;
  will-change: transform, position;
  height: 120px;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  left: 40px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.div-right-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.div-right-2 {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.div-right-3 {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="div-left div-left-small">

    DELIVERING INNOVATION Sustainability goals We are an integrated engineering company comprised of agile and experienced engineers skilled in different types of engineering work.
  </div>
  <div class="div-right-1 div-right-1-small">Environment</div>

  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="div-right-2 div-right-2-small">Health & Safety</div>

  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="div-right-3 div-right-3-small">Integrity</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a background-attachment:fixed

```
.div-right-1{
background-attachment:fixed
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
}
```